# Allowing users to add their custom domain in web app

Tags: dns, cname

I need to build a basic functionality wherein users of my app are able to add their own custom domains for the app. App allows users to create a page which is by default on sub domain for eg. - foo.myapp.com. I want users to enter their custom domain which can replace foo.myapp.com.

For eg. blog.wordpress.com allowing you to use your custom domain.

So my question is what is the best implementation for this.

Do my users have to just simply create a cname record at their registrar and I essentially have to do nothing at my end or is there any other way?

Comment: CNAME should enough for them to reach your server. You need to configure webserver/app to respond, with the correct page.

Comment: What kind of configuration is required at my app? foo.myapp.com already displays the correct user page which I am doing by using middleware to track the subdomain. Users can simply add their CNAME as host 'custom_domain' points to 'foo.myapp.com' , right ?

Comment: You can try. Add `something.example.com` to your hosts file, pointed at your webserver ip addrs, and then open it in your browser

Comment: It worked. Thanks for help